# How to use Navicat to execute and export SQL query via CMD?

Tags: mysql, sql, command-line, command, navicat

I want to load a query from my desktop into Navicat and export the results of that query. Instead of going through the interface I want to do it via the command line. Does anyone know if this is possible?

I think it's possible via `Navicat.exe` or `exportquery` but I cannot get it to work. Can someone post a example of how I would choose my results file location?

[Also, see here.](http://wiki.navicat.com/wiki/index.php/Windows_Commands)

My current non working code is : C:\Program Files\Navicat Premium>navicat /query ConnectionName mydb "C:\Users\User\Desktop\my_mysqlquery.txt" > C:\Users\User\Desktop\outputresults.txt...but I can't get it working

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain what you mean by "not working". Please include **full** tracebacks (if they exist) and a sample that is **small** and **runnable** *on its own* and that reproduces the problem.

Comment: My current non working code is : C:\Program Files\Navicat Premium>navicat /exportquery ConnectionName mydb "QUERY FILE LOCATION" > C:\Users\User\Desktop\outputresults.txt...I can't find any piece of code which is runnable for me hence why I asked here

Comment: Thank you for additional details. Comments aren't the best place to put this, though. You should instead modify your original question to add additional information.